# Condition to compare 2 different number in plugin QGIS

Tags: python-3.x, qgis

I try to make plugin to compare 2 input number, but it going like this

```
  Recomend = self.ui.btnProc
            QtCore.QObject.connect(Recomend, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.Compare1)

        def Compare1(self):
            input1 = self.ui.lineInput1.text()
            input2 = self.ui.lineInput2.text()
            compare = ''
            if input1 == '' + input2:
                compare = 'input match'
            else
                compare = 'input doesnt match'
            self.ui.textRec1.setPlainText(compare)

  File "C:\Users\Mr.Pakde/.qgis2/python/plugins\condition\conditiondialog.py", line 40
    input2 = self.ui.lineInput2.text()
                                    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I check indentation error with notepad++ and PyScripter but still got this error message

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of error Python will give you if you mix tabs and spaces - most likely, the line above the error is indented using hard tabs, and the line with the error indented using spaces. Python is using a wider setting for hard tabs than you, and so the line with that is indented further - even though it looks the same in your editor.

Don't mix them, precisely because it causes these kinds of problems - choose *either* hard tabs *or* spaces, and configure your text editor to do that when you press 'Tab'. Which you choose is something you can Google up all kinds of holy wars on, but choose a side and stick to it.

To fix the error once it's happened, unindent the entire body of the function back to the left margin, then reindent it to the appropriate level. In Notepad++, like in many other editors, you can do this by highlighting all of those lines and pressing Shift+tab to unindent, then Tab to reindent.